# yii2 kartik export menu - No results found

Tags: yii2, export-to-excel

Using [karktik](http://demos.krajee.com/export-demo-dtl/menu-only) export menu only. Why do the following exports an excel file with no results found.. I am sure that there are records inside the TblDv model. But in the excel it says no records found.

-in the controller

```
    public function actionExport(){

        $provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => TblDv::find(),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ],
        ]);

        return $this->render('export', [
            'dataProvider' => $provider,
        ]);

    }
```

-the view

```
<?php
use kartik\export\ExportMenu;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use kartik\helpers\Html;



$gridColumns = [
    'id',
];


echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
    'fontAwesome' => true,
]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but it worked when I changed the gridcolumns to this..

```
$gridColumns=[
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
    ];
```